# Gem from custom git repository is not available

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I tried to modify an existing gem and forked the git repository.
I added some commits and pointed bundler to my GitHub repository.
`bundler update` does recognise the change and downloads my version of the gem.
Anyway when I try to launch the application which depends on that gem (testkitchen) my changes aren't available. And when I delete the official version of the gem my version is not found/used and the app fails.

The weird thing is that all the official gems are installed to `/var/lib/gems` and my version goes to `~/.bundler`

`gem environment` also shows up the correct directories

```
- GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/2.2.0
     - /home/ansible/.bundler/ruby/2.2.0
```

I'm not using rvm or similar. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How are you starting your app? Are you using `bundle exec ...` so that Bundler can set up the load path?

Comment: @matt ahhhhhhh yeah THANK YOU :) forgot about that

Comment: If that was the answer, please add it as an answer and accept it as an answer, for future people viewing this question.

Comment: yeah I will. Just one more thing. Why does only my gem land in the bundler gem dir and not the other gems which are also installed via bundler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @matt pointed out I forgot to add `bundle exec` to my commands.